# Extracting projects to their own repository in svn using svndumpfilter2 (python assertion error)

Tags: python, svn

I'm attempting to migrate a project out of one repository into its own repository to more easily handle authentication/authorization via ldap.  However, in attempting the svnadmin dump | svndumpfilter --include ... I get the standard error that some files in the included path were moved or copied from somewhere NOT in the included path, and thus the contents are not available.

Google tells me that I need to use one of the svndumpfilter python script variants.  I have python 2.6.5 on windows server 2003 accessible via the command line.  All three of these scripts use standard input, but they each handle things a little different.  svndumpfilter2 starts, but on Revision 2, chokes with an assertion failure.  The code apparently expects a colon to be on that line, and there's not.  The dump file I'm using is just a simple svnadmin dump repo > out.dump.  Nothing has been done to it.

The command(s) I'm using are:
svnadmin dump D:\svn\repo | C:\Python26\python.exe "C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Server\svndumpfilter2.py" http: //localhost/svn/repo include Project > D:\svndump\project.dump

OR

svnadmin dump D:\svn\repo > out.dump

type out.dump | C:\Python26\python.exe "C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Server\svndumpfilter2.py" http: //localhost/svn/repo include Project > D:\svndump\project.dump

The output I get is:

> - Dumped revision 0.
> - Dumped revision 1. C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion
> - Server\svndumpfilter2.py:67:
> - DeprecationWa rning: the md5 module is
>     deprecated; use hashlib instead
> - import md5 Traceback (most recent call
>     last):   File "C:\Program
>     Files\CollabNet\Subversion
>     Server\svndumpfilter2.py", line 40 6,
> - in 
>     lump = read_lump(fr)   File "C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion
>     Server\svndumpfilter2.py", line 23 9,
> - in read_lump
>     lump = read_rfc822_headers(f)   File "C:\Program
>     Files\CollabNet\Subversion
>     Server\svndumpfilter2.py", line 23 1,
> - in read_rfc822_headers
>     assert colon > 0 AssertionError

The first part of the dump file it's failing on is:

> SVN-fs-dump-format-version: 2
>
> UUID:
>   880c8176-308d-ea4f-8680-45defe5ec145
>
> Revision-number: 0
>   Prop-content-length: 56
>   Content-length: 56
>
> K 8 svn:date V 27
>   2007-01-30T21:25:29.487250Z PROPS-END
>
> Revision-number: 1
>   Prop-content-length: 151
>   Content-length: 151
>
> K 7 svn:log V 40 Folders added to
>   allow proper branching. K 10
>   svn:author V 15 COMPANY\USER K 8
>   svn:date V 27
>   2007-02-02T21:02:22.321625Z PROPS-END
>
> Node-path: branch Node-kind: dir
>   Node-action: add Prop-content-length:
>   10 Content-length: 10
>
> PROPS-END
>
> Node-path: tags Node-kind: dir
>   Node-action: add Prop-content-length:
>   10 Content-length: 10
>
> PROPS-END
>
> Node-path: trunk Node-kind: dir
>   Node-action: add Prop-content-length:
>   10 Content-length: 10
>
> PROPS-END
>
> Revision-number: 2
>   Prop-content-length: 109
>   Content-length: 109

Has anyone seen this before or have any ideas why this would be occuring?

Answer (score 3):

This error may be occurring because Python-on-Windows is performing newline conversions (treating stdin as a text file).

Because "svnadmin dump" produces a dump file using Unix newline convention (even when run on Windows), you don't want python performing newline conversions. The solution is to invoke python with the "-u" option.

Also, the first argument to svndumpfilter2.py is supposed to be a local REPOS_PATH, not an http:// string. Lets say for sake of discussion that your repository is called foo_bar and resides at c:\svnrepos\foo_bar. Let's also say you have run "svnadmin dump" already on foo_bar and produced a file called out.dump

Then the proper python invocation is:

C:\Python26\python.exe -u "C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Server\svndumpfilter2.py" c:\svnrepos\foo_bar Project D:\svndump\project.dump